# How to start an iex session with cookie and erl options

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, elixir-iex

If I start an `IEx` session in the following manner the cookie is set correctly.

```
$ iex --name example@10.10.10.2 --cookie mycookie -S mix
...
iex(example@10.10.10.2)1> :erlang.get_cookie
:mycookie
```

However if I also set erlang arguments to get use my `sys.config` file the cookie is not set correctly.

```
$ iex --name example@10.10.10.2 --cookie mycookie --erl "config sys.config" -S mix
...
iex(example@10.10.10.2)1> :erlang.get_cookie
:USLOPZLYUPUYMEGXBMJQ
```

How can I set both a config and cookie as command line arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The erlang configuration to set a cookie is `setcookie` not `cookie`. Can be solved by starting as follows.

```
$ iex --name example@10.10.10.2 --erl "-config sys.config -setcookie mycookie" -S mix
```

Comment: So `--erl` overrides `--cookie` in the first example? Sounds like a bug to me. Elixir should either merge them or disallow specifying both `--erl` and `--cookie`.

Comment: agreed. I've started putting all options that work both ways in the --erl arguments to be on the safe side